# Github pages refuses to show images

Tags: github, jekyll

I have pulled my hair out for the last two hours trying to get Github pages to show images.

I made a personal site (username.github.io/) in Jekyll 
and I want to deploy project pages from it. I made a github repo called test-class and turned it into a project page. Github hosts it just fine from username.github.io/test-class, but it refuses to show images.

Here is a basic example. I have this post:

[image]

which looks like this on Github:

[image]

and like this when I serve locally:

[image]

but it is not showing on Github pages:

[image]

even though everything looks good in the browser:

[image]

This exact system works just fine on my personal site (username.github.io). Why on Earth is it failing now?

**EDIT**: I should note that I have tried several different pathnames and none work. I even tried putting the image in the exact same folder as the markdown file. That also does not work.

Comment: try to add site.url `![image will be here]({{ site.url }}/images/llama.jpeg)`

Comment: that will redirect to username.github.io

Comment: try this then `![image will be here]({{ site.baseurl }}/images/llama.jpeg)` I believe `site.baseurl` should have `/test-class` for you

Comment: or even more explicit `![image will be here]({{ site.url }}{{ site.baseurl }}/images/llama.jpeg)`

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I have found so far is to reference the hosted image:

```
![](https://username.github.io/test-class/images/llama.jpeg)
```

**EDIT**. I found the solution last night when I was trying to solve another problem that I thought was different but was actually the same. It turns out that relative links in github pages are very tricky. [This github bug post](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/332?imz_s=74c5cp43e18l6ee6g9ci1i68i3) going back to 2011 pointed this out.

The *only* way you can tell github to host the page from the project repository and not your personal site is by setting `baseurl` in your `_config.yml`:

```
baseurl: test-class/
```

and then name each *image* link (using my example)

```
![]({{site.basurl}}/images/llama.jpeg)
```

while

```
![](test-class/images/llama.jpeg)
```

will *not* work.

The baseurl rule applies for all links. For instance, if you make a `collection` and try to create an index with links to all the pages in that collection, you have to explicitly reference the baseurl:

```
{%- for tutorial in site.tutorials -%}
    <li>
        <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ tutorial.url }}">
        {{ tutorial.title | escape }}
        </a>
    </li>
{%- endfor -%}
```

except now you need to *drop* the trailing `/`.

While this seems obvious now, the Github documentation could to do a better explaining how project pages and personal sites work together.

**EDIT 2**. The `baseurl` trick is not even mentioned in [Jekyll's documents](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/github-pages/). [Here](https://ilovesymposia.com/2015/01/04/some-things-i-learned-while-building-a-site-on-github-pages/) is a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Have a look at: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/tags/#link baseurl is documented with a lot of examples.

Answer (score 0):

Your webpage/website resides in a sub-folder (test-class). You would normally reference this by using the `{{ site.baseurl }}` variable. This should be set in the `_config.yml` file like this (just add this line to the file):

```
baseurl: /test-class
```

Image links still need to have this baseurl in their path, so you would still have to write:

```
![](/test-class/images/llama.jpeg)
```

... or (better) something like yuyokk advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52597903/2397550):

```
![]({{ site.baseurl }}/images/llama.jpeg)
```

This command instructs the server to look at the root of the domain (the first slash) and in the sub-folder 'test-class'. There a folder images should exist, containing a file 'llama.jpeg'.

---

```
![](images/llama.jpeg)
```

Note that the above command might work too for the homepage, as it instructs the server to look at the subfolder 'images' in the location of the current page. For any other page, this might fail, as they might have a different path (another virtual or real folder).

Comment: Thanks @JoostS. I found a similar solution last night and updated my answer. Turns out relative paths are tricky in gh pages.